Как реализовать шифрование писем на почтовом сервере
Есть почтовый сервер IredMail (postfix+dovecot+roundcube) в локальной сети.
Стоит задача реализовать шифрование писем, которые хранятся на сервере, что бы никто кроме самого получателя не мог их прочитать (в том числе и администратор сервера).
Подобное хорошо реализовано у Nextcloud (default_module)
Вариант с PGP не рассматривал, так как создавать каждому пользователю пару ключей займет уйму времени.
Может есть какие-то идеи?
